# Subquery is not introduced with exists, stored procedure

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I've made a stored procedure and got the error message below, dont know why. I've been looking around for some answers and with some other guys here at the office but they're all unsure of the problem. Hoping someone here has had the same problem and knows the solution to this.

```
Msg 116, Level 16, State 1, Procedure Name_Stored_Procedure, 
Line 113 Only one expression can be specified in the select list 
when the subquery is not introduced with EXISTS.
```

Here is my Code

```
 Set @SQLstring = 
 'Update #TempTable set Col1' + case when len(Convert(Varchar, (4+@counter)))=1 
 then '0' else '' end 
 + Convert(Varchar,(4+@counter)) + '=''' + 
 (select @Year, @Month, 
 Convert(Varchar,count(distinct Table.Column1)) 
 from Databse.Table 
 where DATEPART(yy,Time) = @Year 
 and DATEPART(mm,Time) = @Month 
 and Table.Column2 = @Column2 and Column3 in ('X','Z','Y - A')) 
 +''' where row = ' + CONVERT(varchar,10+@somevariable * 12)
 exec('' + @SQLstring +'')
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're going to build a string of SQL and execute it with dynamic SQL, then you need to treat it as a string

```
 Set @SQLstring = 
     'Update #TempTable set Col' 
            + case when len(Convert(Varchar, (4+@counter)))=1 then '0' else '' end
     ...
```

In your inner select, remove the `@year, @month` from the results

```
 + ( select Convert(Varchar,count(distinct Table.Column1)) from databse.Table....
```

Comment: Thank you, sorry it is treated as a string. I've just forgot to type it in the description. Still having the same issue though. 

Cheers

Answer (score 0):

Take the year , month , count  in the below part in separate select queries.

```
(select @Year, @Month, 
 Convert(Varchar,count(distinct Table.Column1)) 
 from Databse.Table 
 where DATEPART(yy,Time) = @Year 
 and DATEPART(mm,Time) = @Month 
 and Table.Column2 = @Column2 and Column3 in ('X','Z','Y - A'))
```

Answer (score 0):

select CONCAT(@year, @month, convert....)